# How can i know the total of elemets using jsonpath expression?

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

i have the next json structure:

```
    [
    {
        "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
        "nationality": "BR",
    },
    {
        "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
        "nationality": "SP",
    },
    {
        "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
        "nationality": "EU",
    }
    ]
```

I want, using jsonpath expression, to know the quantity of elements in my Json Array.

I trying with `$.length` but no work.

How can i know the total of elements using jsonpath expression?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. The trailing comma is displayed as an error in most online validators.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  [
{
    "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
    "nationality": "BR"
},
{
    "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
    "nationality": "SP"
},
{
    "entryDate": "2010-02-25",
    "nationality": "EU"
}
]
```

and then

```
$.length
```